# Django: How to display formset as radio button group

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have my Form and Formset defined as below:

```
class MCQChoiceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Choice
        fields = ['choice_text', 'is_choice_correct']
        labels = {
            'choice_text': "",
            'is_choice_correct': ""
        }
        widgets = {
            "choice_text": forms.Textarea(),  # attrs={'rows': 2, 'cols': 15}
            # "is_choice_correct": # do something here
        }


MCQSingleChoiceFormSet = formset_factory(MCQChoiceForm, min_num=4, max_num=4, extra=0)
```

`MCQSingleChoiceFormSet` represents choices for a problem which can only have once correct choice. `Choice.is_correct_choice` field indicates if the given choice is correct.

**My Question**:

1. How can I display `is_choice_correct` field as a single radio button? True or False values saved in database will depend on whether the radio button is selected or not.
2. How can I change my code so that only one of the radio buttons in the formset is selected?

Answer (score 0):

Here a code you can take a look :

```
CHOICES=[('True','False')]

choose = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect())
```